# How to remove the white border around ggsurvfit plot when risk table is added

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggsurvfit

When a ggsurvfit plot includes a risk table, a white border is automatically added around the entire plot and risk table. This gets apparent when setting panel and background fills.

How can I remove this white border around the plot?

```
library(ggsurvfit)
library(survival)

survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ surg, data = df_colon) |>
  ggsurvfit() +
  add_risktable(theme = list(
    theme_risktable_default(),
    theme(
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "beige"),
      plot.background = element_rect(fill = "beige", color = "beige")
    )
  )) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "beige"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "beige", color = "beige"),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent")
  )
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: `df_colon` is included in the {ggsurvfit} package. The example code is directly copy-pastable.

Answer (score 0):

First, change the default layout.
Then run your code:

```
library(ggsurvfit)
library(survival)

theme_set(theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0))) 

survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ surg, data = df_colon) |>
  ggsurvfit() +
  add_risktable(theme = list(
    theme_risktable_default(),
    theme(
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "beige"),
      plot.background = element_rect(fill = "beige", color = "beige")
    )
  )) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "beige"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "beige", color = "beige"),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent")
  )
```